# Javascript Div Tallest

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, alignment

I'm trying to make a row of divs all match the height of the tallest one, so they look uniform.

I have read about a lot on this, but can't seem to find any solution that works cross browser.

The current script I am using is:

```
    var maxHeight = 1;

    $('.thumbnail').each(function() {
        maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    });

    $('.thumbnail').each(function() {
        $(this).height(maxHeight);
    });
```

Logically I can't see why this wouldn't work?

Works fine in Firefox, but seems to cause issues in Chrome & Safari.

Here is a fiddle for you to use: http://jsfiddle.net/UtMz3/

What is really odd is that it does work in the fiddle, but not on my site.

*UPDATE*

So what is happening is that Chrome is grabbing the DIV height before the image is loaded into it. So Chrome grabs the DIV size at let's say 120px, then the image is being loaded thus changing the DIV size to more like 290px. I can't figure out why this is happening though, seems that being in the $(document).ready({}) wrapper should solve this. I've also tried putting the JavaScript at the bottom of the page, but still the same results.

Any ideas or comments greatly appreciated, 
Kind Regards, 
James

Comment: Well, since it works in the fiddle, on your site you probably have other factors weighing in. You should really try to narrow it down on your site and if you still have a problem post the relevant code here.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you can simplify your code a bit. If you don't need to do anything else in the second `.each()` other than set the height you can remove the loop completely and just do `$('.thumbnail').height(maxHeight);`

Comment: Well in Chrome & Safari the divs get set really small. I'll try and narrow it down some more and let you know. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: OK So the issue is that the maxHeight variable is not getting set correctly. I don't see how this could be a CSS/HTMl issue? Any further ideas?

Comment: You could also try `maxHeight = Math.max($(this).height(), maxHeight);` instead of `maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();`

Comment: OK So I think I've discovered the issue, but no solution. Chrome is giving me the DIV height before any content is actually put in them. Once this happens the height changes, but the javascript has already executed. Why would this happen when it's in the $(document).ready({}) wrapper?

Comment: How are you populating the content?  Is it via ajax? If not are the elements hidden at any stage?

Comment: The data is being loaded through PHP, but so is the text and that loads before the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to examine how the content is being placed into those divs.  If it isn't there yet on `$(document).ready()`, then the content is probably being dynamically added and you will need to wait until after it is added to measure.

How you wait until after the content is there depends upon how it is being added.

`$(document).ready()` does NOT wait for images to load.  You would need to use `$(window).load()` for that so if the content includes images, then you will need to find a way to wait for them to load.  `$(window).load()` will wait for all images to load or you can install `load` event handlers on each image object that isn't yet loaded to get notified when they finish loading.

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question, you beat me too it :). Thanks this works perfectly.